# Many-To-Many issue (MVC3 + EF4.1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm working in MVC 3 and EF 4.1, and I'm at beginners level.

So I've declared these 2 classes:

```
public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Show> Shows { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Show
{
    [Key]
    public int ShowId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual int[] GenreIds { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
 }
```

Now I'm trying to display details on particular show and loop&display through genres that show has been tagged with. I have a standard Details view that I'm using, so I'm passing the following to it, from controller:

```
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Show show = db.Shows.Find(id);
        return View(show);
    }
```

And I'm using this Razor loop to show genres:

```
@foreach (ShowCat.Models.Genre Genre in Model.Genres)
{
    @Html.Display(Genre.Name)
}
```

And absolutely nothing happens...

No genres shown...

Help please!

Comment: of course, you return the Show object rather than the Genre. And it is not a list type either.

Comment: My view model is strongly-typed to show, so when calling Model.Genres, I'm actually calling for passed show.Genres

Comment: OK, then you need to disable the laze loading.

Comment: When I add breakpoint, right before invoking View(show), I can actually see that my show has property Genres, that's filled up with proper genres. But it still does not show on the view when looping it. So I don't think the problem is with lazy loading...

Comment: Because when you hover the mouse cursor on the property and expand the content in Visual Studio, the debugger loads that data for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML helper `Html.Display(string expression)` requires that you pass in the name of a model property, not the value of a property. By passing in `Genre.Name` into the method you pass in something like "Heavy Metal" which is apparently not a name of any property in your model.

The easiest fix is to replace `Html.Display` by `Html.DisplayFor`:

```
@foreach (ShowCat.Models.Genre Genre in Model.Genres)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Genre.Name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled **lazy-loading**?

If so, you probably need to **eager-load** the Genre's:

```
var show = db.Shows.EagerLoad(x => x.Genres).SingleOrDefault(id);
```

Also this:

```
@foreach (ShowCat.Models.Genre Genre in Model.Genres)
{
    @Html.Display(Genre.Name)
}
```

Can be shortened to this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genres)
```

By adding a editor template for "Genre": (Genre.cshtml)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
```

Comment: I had disabled it (by setting Virtual prefix), and my goal is to keep it that way, as this is the only view where I want genres to display for particular show. This function "EagerLoad" is not known to me, and IntelliSense isn't showing it for me either, what namespace does it belong to? I'm working with MVC 3 + Entity Framework 4.1.

Comment: Using @DisplayFor(model => model.Genres) gives me this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShowCat.Models.Show]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShowCat.Models.Show]

Comment: Ok I "solved" the problem, by doing this:     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Genres.Count; i++)
    {
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genres[i].Name); But I have no idea why is "for" loop working and "foreach" isn't...
    }

Comment: @BarisaPuter: It's not the `for` loop which makes the difference but the use of `DisplayFor` instead of `Display` (see my answer). And: I think, RPM1984 meant `Include` instead of `EagerLoad`. `Include` should be available, though you don't need it as lazy loading seems to work for you.

Comment: Yep, my bad, `Include` is what i meant. Don't use loops, use editor/display templates. Also, lazy loading in views is *very* bad practice, in fact it breaks the MVC pattern.

Comment: I tried with Include at the very start, it made no difference. I did however change my code now at the controller to: var show = db.Shows.Include("Genres").Where(s => s.ShowId == id).FirstOrDefault(); so that should send lazy loading off the view and back to controller. Thanks for your tips dudes!

Comment: @BarisaPuter - i think you need to read up a bit more on lazy loading vs eager loading. In your above comment, that is *eager loading*, since you are explicitly asking EF to fetch the Genres. So your view for loop will enumerate over an in-memory collection. If you get rid of the Include, that is *lazy loading*, where each enumeration in your view will force a query to the db. The former is good practice, the latter **bad**. Also, don't use `FirstOrDefault()` when your querying upon a PK. There should never be more than one, so you should use `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Lapsus linguae... I meant I took lazy loading off the view, but I forgot to say that I'm using eager loading now (as I actually do need all genres to be pre-loaded for that particular view) so I do understand the difference between the two :) As for SingleOrDefault vs FirstOrDefault, I guess you're right about that one, I just didn't think it makes much of a difference which one I use. I've tried few more solutions, but I still can't make foreach to loop through my genres - and that still bugs my mind. Find solution for the initial problem, but ? mark still remains :)

Comment: @BarisaPuter - don't use foreach. Just use templates, like i said in my answer, and it will work.